# How to filter images of specific size with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing

I'm trying to find images larger than a specific size in an HTML page, but the following code does not work correctly:

```
function findImages(url)
{
  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            var html = $.parseHTML( data ), 
                imgs = $(html).find("img").filter(function() {
                    return ($(this).width() > 50) && ($(this).height() > 50)
                });
            len = imgs.length; 
            if( len > 0 ){
                $.each(imgs, function(index, img) {
                    console.log(img.width);
                });
            } else {
                console.log("Image not found");
            }
        },
    });
};
```

I expect the `filter` part to return images whose `width` and `height` is larger than 50, but it does not seem to work for me. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You haven't appended the elements to the document. Also the images should be loaded before you get the dimensions.

Comment: @Vohuman How can I wait for images to load?

Comment: You can listen to the `load` event.

Comment: @Vohuman of which object?

Comment: I thought that's what the success object in the ajax call was ? Just a side note, not sure if this will work if they haven't got a width / height set in the html. ## Edit, It will work apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose html response look like this

```
var imagesHTML = [
  '<img src="http://" width="100" height="500">',
  '<img src="http://" width="100" height="500">',
  '<img src="http://" width="50" height="500">',
  '<img src="http://" width="50" height="50">',
  '<img src="http://" width="100" height="50">',
  '<img src="http://" width="50" height="50" style="width: 100px">'
];

var html = $(images.join(''));
```

#1 - *filter by html attributes*

```
var imgs = html.find("img").filter(function() {
  return ($(this).attr('width') > 50) && ($(this).attr('height') > 50);
});
// push to DOM
```

#2 *Filter by width (inline styles)*

```
var doc = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    div = document.createElement('div');

var imgs = $(div).html(html).find('img').filter(function () {
   return ($(this).width() > 50) && ($(this).height() > 50)
});
// push to DOM
```

#3 - [example](http://jsbin.com/rused/7/edit?js,output) - if width and height attributes have not been setted for images

```
function loadImages(content, callback) {
  var html   = $(content),
      urls   = [];

  function filter(width, height) {
    return (width > 256 && height > 256);
  }

  function load(el) {
    var def = new $.Deferred(),
        img = new Image();

    img.onload = function () {
      if (filter(img.width, img.height)) {        
        return def.resolve(el.get(0));
      }

      def.resolve(null);
    };

    img.onerror = function () {
      def.resolve();
    };

    img.src = el.attr('src');

    return def;
  }

  urls = $('<div />').html(html).find('img').map(function () {
    return load($(this));      
  }).get();


  $.when.apply(null, urls).done(function () {    
    callback.call(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 0).filter(Boolean));
  });
}

loadImages(images.join(''), function (images) {
  var content = $('<div />');

  images.forEach(function (el) {
    content.append(el);  
  }); 

  $('body').html(content.get(0));
});
```

*In my opinion better send JSON which will contain all images (**urls**) :), because creating unnecessary HTTP queries it's not good solution.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get every image corresponding your needs, loop through every image in your page and check for it :

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length ; i++) {
    if (img[i].width > 2) {
        // Do your thing
    }
}
```

And if you have a particular image target and know it's ID, it's even easier :

```
if (document.getElementById('#theone').width() > 2) {
        // Do your thing
}
```

Note : this is plain javascript, if you use jQuery just change the bits of syntax that corresponds

```
var img = $('img');
for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length ; i++) {
    if (img[i].width > 2) {
        // Do your thing
    }
}
```

and

```
if ($('#theone').width() > 2) {
        // Do your thing
}
```